# sort arrays can't get method to work

Tags: c

A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions.A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions.

Comment: `x < sort` what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: the listNames prompt by users

Comment: You cannot compare an `int` (x) with an array of Strings (sort). You probably meant to compare it with the length if sort, which is `sort.length`.

Comment: Dont' remove your question..Let it to be there as it was..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
for (int x = 0; x < sort; x++)
```

to

```
for (int x = 0; x < sort.length; x++)
```

instead. And

```
String[] sort = new String[listNames];
```

to

```
String[] sort = new String[listNames.length];
```

Also , `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` should be used in this way:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Tutor LAST NAME and FIRST NAME Listed in Alphabetically Order"+(x+1)+ " " + "For example: 'Smith, John'");
```

Comment: did i get the method right atleast or atleast in order or on the right track

Comment: wow that help!. i only have one error now which is PeerTutorReport.java:46: error: illegal start of expression
  for (int x = 0; x < sort.length; x++)) {
                                       ^
1 error

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.

Comment: PeerTutorReport.java:49: error: no suitable method found for showMessageDialog(String)
  sort[x] = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(" Tutor LAST NAME and FIRST NAME Listed in Alphabetically Order"+(x+1)+ " " + "For example: 'Smith, John'");

Comment: `for (int x = 0; x < sort.length; x++))` remove the last `)` bracket here.

Comment: method JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component,Object,String,int,Icon) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component,Object,String,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: You changed the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` as I have posted in my code?

Comment: can you email me at angie4911@yahoo.com ? so i can chat with you

Answer (score 1):

In the following three code blocks I'll first write your line and then what it should be:

```
String[] sort = new String[listNames];
String[] sort = new String[listNames.length];
                                    ^^^^^^^
```

---

```
for (int x = 0; x < sort; x++) {
for (int x = 0; x < sort.length; x++) {
                        ^^^^^^^
```

---

```
sort[x] = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(" Tutor LAST NAME and FIRST NAME Listed in Alphabetically Order"+(x+1)+ " " + "For example: 'Smith, John'");
sort[x] = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Tutor LAST NAME and FIRST NAME Listed in Alphabetically Order"+(x+1)+ " " + "For example: 'Smith, John'");
                                        ^^^^^
```

Assuming you really want to create a new array prior to sorting it, your method should be:

```
public static String[] sortNames(String[] listNames) {
    String[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(listNames, listNames.length);
    Arrays.sort(copy);
    return copy;
}
```

If it has to be a method, but you don't have to create a second array, you could do this:

```
public static void sortNames(String[] listNames) {
    Arrays.sort(listNames);
}
```